# I'm getting a net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE with socket.io/node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Here is the current code that I am using to try to connect my web application running socket.io to my node application.

```
var options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('csgo2x.key').toString(),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('csgo2x.crt').toString(),
  ca : [fs.readFileSync("csgo2x.pem").toString()],
  rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var server = require('https').createServer(options);
var portNo = 443;
server.listen(portNo, function() {
  console.log((new Date()) + " Server is listening on port " + portNo);
});
```

However...when I try to connect my socket.io application running on my Ubuntu server...it gives the error `net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE`.

I am using certificates from Cloudflare btw and for some reason it's not working

Comment: Did u try to run the your script as root